# jest test fails with refs and Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a search bar component which looks like:

```
  render () {
    const { onChangeTextInput } = this.props
    return (
      <Form
        name="searchForm"
        ref={(ref) => {
          this.searchForm = ref
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          noSpacing
          placeholder={t('search')}
          name="search"
          validate="text"
          icon={this.icon}
          onChangeTextCallback={() => {
            onChangeTextInput(this.searchForm.values)
          }}
        />
        )
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

I am using a shallow render and jest to run a unit test to test the following scenario"

1. User types a character in text input
2. a callback method gets fired which provides the user with the text as an argument.

The test I am running is stated as:

```
 test('SearchBar returns value on text change', () => {
        const onChangeFunction = jest.fn()
        const obj = shallow(
          <SearchBar onChangeTextInput={onChangeFunction} />
        )
        obj.find('TextInput').props().onChangeTextCallback('h')
        expect(onChangeFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('h')
      })
```

I getting a weird error stating :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined

  51 |           icon={this.icon}
  52 |           onChangeTextCallback={() => {
> 53 |             onChangeTextInput(this.searchForm.values)
     |                                                 ^
  54 |           }}
  55 |         />
  56 |         )
```

My obj.html() dump for the test looks like:

```
<Form name="searchForm" if={true}>
  <TextInput
    noSpacing={true}
    placeholder="search"
    name="search"
    validate="text"
    icon={{
      $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
      type: [(Function: Icon)],
      key: null,
      ref: null,
      props: {
        name: "search",
        size: 25,
        color: "#00a8ca",
        style: { position: "absolute", right: 0, bottom: 7 },
        allowFontScaling: false,
        type: "MaterialIcons",
        if: true,
      },
      _owner: null,
      _store: {},
    }}
    onChangeTextCallback={[(Function: onChangeTextCallback)]}
    value={null}
    style={{}}
    hasFloatingLabel={true}
    numberOfLines={1}
    isPassword={false}
    if={true}
  />
  )
</Form>
```

what is happening here? I have custom form that gives me values through refs. Do I need to do something and maybe initialize the Form component? please help, I am relatively new to this stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issue**

The `ref` callback isn't getting called so `this.searchForm` is `undefined` when `onChangeTextCallback()` is invoked.

**Details**

From the [Callback Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) docs: "React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the component mounts".

In the test you are using `shallow()`.  Shallow rendering does not mount the component so the `ref` callback is never called.

**Solution**

Mount the component.  Since you are already using `Enzyme` you can use [`mount()`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html).  Note that "full DOM rendering requires that a full DOM API be available at the global scope", for `Jest` you can [configure the test environment to use `jsdom`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string).

Comment: Can you show me how and where to use mount? I don;t believe jsdom works with react native

Comment: `import { mount } from 'enzyme';` instead of `import { shallow } from 'enzyme';`, then call `mount()` instead of `shallow()`.  To use `jsdom` in the test you can add the `@jest-environment` docblock for `jsdom` at the top of the test file [like they do in the example here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string).  `jsdom` just adds the DOM API to the global scope, it works fine with react native.

Comment: Thanks trying it now :)

Comment: Hey Thanks just made it work. Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301227/running-mount-in-react-native-not-possible tried a different approach.